# Positive integers $x$ and $y$ satisfy $34x=43y$. Prove that $x+y$ is composite.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, prime-numbers

I started by saying that $x=43k$ since 34 and 43 are relatively prime. Therefore, $34*43*k=43y$. $y$ equals $34k$, so $x+y$ is $77k$. $77$ is composite, so I have proved it. Is this proof correct?

Comment: i think your proof is ok

Comment: Yes. Correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine.  A bit quicker:  Add $34y$ to both sides to get

$$34(x+y) = 77y$$

and you get immediately that $77 \mid x+y.$